# Excel Cross check 2 arrays with wildcard

Tags: excel-formula

I have no idea how to describe this but I'm so stuck and out of ideas so I will try.

I want to check if an item from one list is in another list that contains a wildcard

you can do the reversed thing with COUNTIF

example.
[LIST]
"Find ME Now",
"Find ME Later"

COUNTIF(LIST; "Find * Now")
This will result in a "match" because the wildcard is in the second argument.

But what i Want is the list to contain wildcards and still get a match
like

[LIST]
"Find * Now"
"Find * Later"

COUNTIF(LIST; "Find ME Now");

The above does now work but im trying to find something that does.

I made a VBA function that does what I want but that was running so slow because of a 1600 list * 10 list * 60 cells....

Edit:

I solved this problem with VBA and a global stored variable of results.

Comment: Just wondering if the patterns to be searched in are always of the form "<string1> * <string2>", which might make things a bit easier, or if they are arbitrary patterns including wildcards?

Comment: No they are different this was just an easy example :)

Comment: Just for the record I was thinking of =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$4,B2))) where B2 contains "Find ME Now" and A2:A4 contain the search patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be worth sharing this even though @laxxen has a solution to the question.

You can set up a 'do-it-yourself' method of counting matches between the search string and the patterns. One formula I tried was the array formula

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,B2)))
```

i.e. try the string in B2 with each of the wildcard patterns using SEARCH and count the number of positive results.

However I don't think this is quite right because SEARCH attempts a match at every position in the 'within' text, so if you want the case where it only matches starting at the beginning of the 'within' text, you need something like (another array formula)

```
=SUM(--IFERROR((SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,B2)=1),0))
```

This shows the results using the two formulae:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you this solution was even better :)

Comment: Glad it helped! I thought it was quite an interesting question.